# You onPaymentSuccess method is throwing an error. Wrap the entire code of the method inside a try catch

Tags: android, try-catch, razorpay

This is my first question. I would like to thank you for the effort and your time in answering this question.

Issue: I am implementing the razorpay on Android using retrofit in JAVA.
after the successful payment on razerpay I get error "You onPaymentSuccess method is throwing an error. Wrap the entire code of the method inside a try catch"

I tried wrapping everything inside try catch, still same error.
Here is my onPaymentSuccess method.

````
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s) {
        
        try {
        tragectionID = s;
        paymentsucsses = 1;
        OrderSumrryFragment.orderID = orderID;

            OrderSumrryFragment.totHash = hashSHA256(String.valueOf(gl_int_tot)+s);
            OrderSumrryFragment.orderHash = hashSHA256(orderID);
            OrderSumrryFragment.tidHash = hashSHA256(s);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Payment Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }```

Not sure where I am going wrong. any help is greatly appriciated.
thank you
Daya
````

Comment: You have a number of spelling mistakes in your code, are they consistent? i.e. is `OrderSumrryFragment` the name of the class?  Does it have a method called `totHash`?

Comment: Hi Prieber,
Spelling mistakes yes, but they are consistent across project. and
OrderSumrryFragment  doesnt have a method but a public string, I am passing hashing  value of total amount onto.

public class OrderSumrryFragment extends Fragment implements GetResult.MyListener {

    final int UPI_PAYMENT = 0;
    public static String orderHash;
    public static String tidHash;
    public static String totHash;